# How to decommission a yarn node gracefully?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I want to decommission a yarn node. But some tasks are still running on the node. I want the node dose not accept tasks anymore.And after the tasks finished, the node start to decommission.

How should I do?

Any advice are appreciated.

I tried to put the hostname of the node into excludeHosts.But it could decommission the node immediately. And tasks failed.